# Adding a variable from a button to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $("button").click(function() {

    btn_id =(this.id);

  });


  $('#button_1').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed) {

    itemid = $(this).attr("data-id") ;

    window.alert(itemid);

  });
```

I want to add the variable of `btn_id` to `button`_1. Could you guys please tell me how to achieve this. I would be willing to accept modified code if needed.

Comment: Wrong tag this is not javascript ,jquery

Comment: add where to `button_1 `

Answer (score 0):

You may want to achieve the following. Hope this will help you.

```js
var btn_id;

$("#button").click(function() {
       btn_id = this.id;
});

$('#button_1').click(function() {
       $(this).data('id', btn_id);

       var itemid = $(this).data('id');
       alert(itemid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="button" value="button"/>
<input type="button" id="button_1" value="button 1"/>
```